# How to add a 2d array to a database in python

Tags: python, mysql, arrays

I am trying to add a list of values into a table in a database

```
QuestionAnswer = [['x','y','z'],['x','y','z']]

(cursor.executemany('INSERT question (QuizID,question,answer) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)',QuestionAnswer)

db.commit()
```

the error is the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\georgia
>   vost\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1705, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "C:\Users\georgia vost\Documents\Private Document\NEA WORK\Code
>   Folder\appJar\appjar.py", line 3494, in 
>       return lambda *args: funcName(param)   File "C:\Users\georgia vost\Documents\Private Document\NEA WORK\Code Folder\prastice program
>   1.py", line 37, in press
>       cursor.executemany('INSERT question (QuizID,question,answer) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)',QuestionAnswer)   File "C:\Users\georgia
>   vost\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py",
>   line 675, in executemany
>       self.execute(operation, params)   File "C:\Users\georgia vost\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py",
>   line 557, in execute
>       psub = _ParamSubstitutor(self._process_params(params))   File "C:\Users\georgia
>   vost\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py",
>   line 437, in _process_params
>       "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % err) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing
>   format-parameters; Python 'method' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Answer (score 0):

There are possibly many changes required in your existing code including query syntax

```
cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO question (QuizID,question,answer) VALUES (?,?,?)',list(map(tuple,QuestionAnswer)))
```